# Enabling or disabling checkboxes due to some user data

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm trying to disable some checkboxes in a `TabHost` I have.  When the app loads it should check to see if some user data (found in `characterData.getCharacterClass()` and `characterData.getCharacterRace()`) is null and if so disables the checkboxes in the "Skills" tab.  Sadly it doesn't disable the checkboxes (also it should enable them when `characterData.getCharacterClass()` and `characterData.getCharacterRace()` are true or otherwise contain data).  I have tried setting an `OnFocusChangedListener()` to check for this data when the focus is switched to the "Skills" tab, but as you can probably see that doesn't work.

[Edit #3]  Arash A. has a good lead.  I was looking at the wrong LinearLayout for moving through the various checkboxes.

[Edit #2] I have tried using the OR operator, as suggested, but that doesn't work, either.  I think my problem is how I go through the Views in my `changeSkillCheckboxes()` function.  I think it's because I only come up with two child Views instead of all of the necessary checkboxes.  Now all I need to do is figure out how to actually get all of the checkboxes.

[Edit #1] I have tried the first suggestion given to me.  But that didn't work, as well.  Maybe it's in the method which is suppose to disable the checkboxes.  Here's the code for that:

```
public void changeSkillCheckboxes(boolean toggle) {
     if (toggle) {
         for (int i = 0; i < skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
                  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i);
                  cb.setEnabled(false);
                  Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Box disabled.");
                    } else {
                      Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "CheckBox wasn't found, with count " + i);
                    }
                 }   
         } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                      if (skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) { 
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        cb.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                    }
                 }
     }
```

The code checks to see if what's being changed are checkboxes, or else it will throw an error (I also have a scroll layout in there).

Any way, here's the code for the two classes:

Tabs file

```
package com.androidGuy.DnDApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

public class CreateCharacterTabsActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener  {
private static final String DEBUG_LOG = "DnDAppDebugInfo";

private TabHost tabHost;
private TableLayout scoreTable;
private LinearLayout raceLayout;
private LinearLayout characterClassesLayout;
private LinearLayout skillLayout;


private CharacterAbilityScoresActivity abilityScoresActivity;
private CharacterRaceActivity raceActivity;
private SkillChooserActivity skillActivity;

// Tab tags: got to love them.
private static final String ABILITY_SCORES_TAB = "scores";
private static final String RACE_TAB = "race";
private static final String CLASS_TAB = "classes";
private static final String SKILL_TAB = "skills";

CharacterData characterData = new CharacterData();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

    // Set up them tabs.
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost01);
    // Set up the tabhost.
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    // Ability scores
    abilityScoresActivity = new CharacterAbilityScoresActivity(this) ;
    scoreTable = (TableLayout) abilityScoresActivity.getAbilityScoreTable();
    // Character race
    raceActivity = new CharacterRaceActivity(this);
    raceLayout = (LinearLayout) raceActivity.getRacesLayout();
    // Character class
    characterClassesLayout = (LinearLayout) (new CharacterClassActivity(this)).getCharacterClassLayout();
    // Class skills
    skillActivity = new SkillChooserActivity(this);
    skillLayout = (LinearLayout) skillActivity.getSkillsCheckboxLayout();

    /* Check to see if the user has selected a race and class.  Once they have enable the skills checkboxes. */
    // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
    skillLayout.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (characterData.getCharacterClass() == null && characterData.getRace() == null) {
                skillActivity.changeSkillCheckboxes(true); // Disable the skill checkboxes
                Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Skill checkboxes disabled.");
            } else {
                skillActivity.changeSkillCheckboxes(false); // Enable the skill checkboxes
                Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Skill checkboxes enabled.");
            }
        }
    }

    );

    // Add views to the tab host.
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(ABILITY_SCORES_TAB).setIndicator("Scores").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return scoreTable;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(RACE_TAB).setIndicator("Races").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg1) {
            return raceLayout;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(CLASS_TAB).setIndicator("Classes").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg2) {
            return characterClassesLayout;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(SKILL_TAB).setIndicator("Skills").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg3) {
            return skillLayout;
        }
    }

    ));

    // I have heard this is a hack brought upon by a bug.
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}


public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Skills file

```
package com.androidGuy.DnDApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class SkillChooserActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

// Character information
CharacterData characterData = new CharacterData();

LinearLayout skillsCheckboxLayout;
Context leContext;
private static final String DEBUG_LOG = "DnDAppDebugInfo";

// Skill checkbox member variables
private CheckBox acrobaticsCheckBox;
private CheckBox arcanaCheckBox;
private CheckBox athleticsCheckBox;
private CheckBox bluffCheckBox;
private CheckBox diplomacyCheckBox;
private CheckBox dungeoneeringCheckBox;
private CheckBox enduranceCheckBox;
private CheckBox healCheckBox;
private CheckBox historyCheckBox;
private CheckBox insightCheckBox;
private CheckBox intimidateCheckBox;
private CheckBox natureCheckBox;
private CheckBox perceptionCheckBox;
private CheckBox religionCheckBox;
private CheckBox stealthCheckBox;
private CheckBox streetwiseCheckBox;
private CheckBox thieveryCheckBox;

SkillChooserActivity(Context mContext) {
    leContext = mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) leContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    skillsCheckboxLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_skill_selector, null);

    /* And now, lots and lots of checkboxes. */
    acrobaticsCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.AcrobaticsCheckBox);
    acrobaticsCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    arcanaCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.ArcanaCheckBox);
    arcanaCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    athleticsCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.AthleticsCheckBox);
    athleticsCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    bluffCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.BluffCheckBox);
    bluffCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    diplomacyCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.DiplomacyCheckBox);
    diplomacyCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    dungeoneeringCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.DungeoneeringCheckBox);
    dungeoneeringCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    enduranceCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.EnduranceCheckBox);
    enduranceCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    healCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.HealCheckBox);
    healCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    historyCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.HistoryCheckBox);
    historyCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    insightCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.InsightCheckBox);
    insightCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    intimidateCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.IntimidateCheckBox);
    intimidateCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    natureCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.NatureCheckBox);
    natureCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    perceptionCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.PerceptionCheckBox);
    perceptionCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    religionCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.ReligionCheckBox);
    religionCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    stealthCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.StealthCheckBox);
    stealthCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    streetwiseCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.StreetwiseCheckBox);
    streetwiseCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    thieveryCheckBox = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.ThieveryCheckBox);
    thieveryCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);

     }
 public void changeSkillCheckboxes(boolean toggle) {
     if (toggle) {
         for (int i = 0; i < skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
                  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i);
                  cb.setEnabled(false);
                  Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Box disabled.");
                    } else {
                      Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "CheckBox wasn't found, with count " + i);
                    }
                 }   
         } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                      if (skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) { 
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        cb.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                    }
                 }
     }

public LinearLayout getSkillsCheckboxLayout() {
    return skillsCheckboxLayout;
}

/* Check their state. */
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(leContext, "You selected " + ((TextView)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "com.anddroidguy.SkillChooserActivity: the value of \'Class\' is " + characterData.getCharacterClass());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(leContext, "Okay, I guess you can select something else...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "com.anddroidguy.SkillChooserActivity: the value of \'Class\' is " + characterData.getCharacterClass());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be from this statement:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) skillsCheckboxLayout.getChildAt(i);
```

Try changing it to this when you are getting the checkbox:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
```

Comment: That's part of the solution, Arash A.  I was looking through the wrong LinearLayout in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `onTabChanged` method.

```
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    if (SKILL_TAB.equals(tag)) {
        // Do your check
        // Maybe should be OR?
        if (characterData.getCharacterClass() == null && characterData.getRace() == null) {
            skillActivity.changeSkillCheckboxes(true); // Disable the skill checkboxes
            Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Skill checkboxes disabled.");
        } else {
            skillActivity.changeSkillCheckboxes(false); // Enable the skill checkboxes
            Log.i(DEBUG_LOG, "Skill checkboxes enabled.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, user802421, that didn't work.  Thank you for trying, though. :D

Comment: Could you post your `CharacterData` class? Are you sure that the check should'nt be `if (characterData.getCharacterClass() == null || characterData.getRace() == null)` (OR operator)?